# Нужно ли выделить запятыми «потрясший до глубины души»?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, определения, уточнения

Будет ли это некое уточнение, которое требует постановки знаков препинания?

*...всё ещё помню тот(,) потрясший меня до глубины души(,) случай.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Хорошо эта тема раскрыта в ПАС.

> § 50. **Не обособляются** определения нераспространенные и с зависимыми словами, стоящие после местоимений **отрицательных, неопределенных, указательных, определительных**, образующие с ними единую группу (ударение падает на определение)...

В этом случае запятые не требуются:
*...всё ещё помню **тот потрясший** меня до глубины души случай.*

*Все эти долгие годы Жан-Жак не вспоминал ни **тот потрясший** его в юности женский
портрет, ни его творца — старого художника, умершего одиноким и безвестным* (А. Манфред. Смерть Жан-Жака).
*Я поймал себя на том, что все еще ищу ту девушку, **тот потрясший** меня образ* (Н. Казурова).
*Мне карманные деньги крайне нужны. Без денег ни один нормальный человек нынче не живет! — снова и снова вспоминал Юрий Юрьевич **тот потрясший** его разговор* (С. Залыгин. Уроки правнука Вовки).

> Однако при наличии уточняющего и ограничительного значения определения **обособляются**: *Вошедший что-то пошептал сидящему, и **тот, совершенно расстроенный**, поднялся со стула* (Булг.)...
> Ср.: *Вон **тот**, маленький, уже приближается к финишу* (определение *маленький* конкретизирует значение местоимения *тот*, т. е указывает на маленького среди всех остальных) — *Вон **тот маленький** уже приближается к финишу* (определением является указательное местоимение *тот*, а определяемым — *маленький*; смысл: указывают на одного из маленьких)...

Если по задумке автора в контексте нужно выделить один особенный (потрясший, необыкновенный) случай из нескольких (обычных, рядовых), то запятые, конечно же, можно поставить.

У Розенталя:

> Уточняющие определения могут конкретизировать общее значение местоимений ***этот, тот, такой, каждый, один*** (в значении местоимения) и т. п.: *Хотелось отличиться перед этим, **дорогим для меня**, человеком* (М. Г.); *Затем удивила Дашу «доморощенность» всего этого, **так нашумевшего**, дерзновения* (А. Т.); *Эти, **не всегда твёрдые и стройные**, стихотворные строки писала рука, твёрдая, как сталь* (Сим.)...

[Знаки препинания при обособленных согласованных определениях](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=118#pp118)
[Уточняющие члены предложения](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=118#pp118)

Comment: А тема весьма обширная... Спасибо. Нужно будет внимательно всё перечитать, чтобы до конца осознать.

Comment: Да, Вы правы, тема эта не просто обширна, но часто весьма спорна. Иногда приходится *крутить-вертеть*, чтобы правильно расставить знаки. А главное: чтобы вашу мысль, ваше ви́дение правильно поняли.

Answer (score 2):

Здесь не всё так просто, как в ответе у Риммы.

Чтобы не ставить запятые, могут быть две причины:
1) *тот потрясший меня до глубины души случай;* || Есть и другой либо другие потрясшие до глубины души случаи. Неоднородные определения. Такое здесь не подходит.
И об этом даже у Розенталя сказано:
*Это искусство заставляет вспомнить те, давно прошедшие, времена, когда исследователи отрицали значение и роль народа в создании памятников архитектуры* (при отсутствии обособления получилось бы, что есть «те давно прошедшие времена» и еще какие-то другие «давно прошедшие времена»).
2) *тот потрясший меня до глубины души случай.* || Уже не новость, что этот случай потряс до глубины души. Такое наблюдается в примерах Риммы. А здесь не похоже, что это так, и запятые, скорее всего, нужны.
Но и в таком случае допустимо уточнение:
*...всё ещё помню тот, а именно потрясший меня до глубины души, случай.*

Если вышеприведённое здесь не задумывается, то запятые нужны. Правило Розенталя таково:
Уточняющие определения могут конкретизировать общее значение местоимений *этот, **тот**, такой, каждый, один* (в значении местоимения) и т. п.:
*Хотелось отличиться перед этим, дорогим для меня, человеком (М. Г.).

Затем удивила Дашу «доморощенность» всего этого, так нашумевшего, дерзновения (А. Т.).

Эти, не всегда твёрдые и стройные, стихотворные строки писала рука, твёрдая, как сталь (Сим.).

Между ними давно уже установились те, чисто формальные, отношения, которые так обычны между двумя родственниками (М. Г.).

Чичиков немного озадачился таким, отчасти резким, определением (Г.).

Каждому, приехавшему и пришедшему, они должны были найти и указать место для ночлега (Ч.).

Ни одного, ни санного, ни человеческого, ни звериного, следа не было видно (Л. Т.).

Произошло нечто, столь необычное в мире, что всё бывалое, привычное будто заколебалось в своей власти над жизнью (Фед.).*

В таких случаях можно переставить оборот:
*...всё ещё помню тот случай, потрясший меня до глубины души.*
Чем больше слов в обороте, тем лучше звучит уточнение, а их здесь много. Без запятых звучит не очень удачно. Если всё же было известно о потрясении до глубины души и уточнения нет (запятые не нужны), то лучше изменить предложение, чтобы нормально звучало, например:
*...всё ещё помню тот случай, что потряс меня до глубины души.*

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. И у Риммы ответ не так уж прост для меня) Тема с "заковыркой", вроде ясно, а как начинаешь задумываться, то... Ещё раз спасибо за детальное пояснение.